# Can Android mobile be an external video card in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, video, android

I want to make an Android phone work as an additional video card while it charges from USB. Not just a „remote desktop“, but a fully-functional video card with working GPU.

As far as I understand, it can be made by emulating a generic OpenGL-compatible video card and forwarding all access to the server part on the mobile phone. Looks simple, but I wonder if those solutions exist.

Comment: You could use an Android phone for a doorstop or a brick, but using a real doorstop or brick would be a lot cheaper.

Comment: iPhone solutions also count, but I doubt they exist. Just being curious, can I forward OpenGL to a card on another *UBUNTU* PC? A „stub driver“ which does nothing but connecting to a server on that PC, and server works with installed card as most games do. Looks incredibly simple.